# Почему не работает @Qualifier в @Service?

Tags: java, spring

Есть интерфейс

```
package ioc.primary_annotation;

public interface Animal {

    void display();

}
```

его реализуют два класса

```
package ioc.primary_annotation;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("kitty")
public class Cat implements Animal {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Cat.display");
    }
}
```

и

```
package ioc.primary_annotation;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("doggi")
public class Dog implements Animal {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Dog.display");
    }
}
```

есть класс конфигурации

```
package ioc.primary_annotation;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ioc.primary_annotation")
public class AppConfig {
}
```

и сервис

```
package ioc.primary_annotation;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AnimalService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("kitty")
    private Animal animal;

    public AnimalService() {
    }

    public Animal getAnimal() {
        return animal;
    }

    public void setAnimal(Animal animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }
}
```

и всё это должно работать в методе main

```
package ioc.primary_annotation;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class PrimaryMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Animal animal = applicationContext.getBean(Animal.class);
        animal.display();

    }

}
```

Но не работает, падает исключение

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ioc.primary_annotation.Animal' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: kitty,doggi
```

Вопрос в том почему это не работает, ведь я указал через Qualifier какой бин нжуно использовать? Если я над классом Cat или Dog укажу анотацию @Primary, то всё магическим образом начинает работать, подскажите в чём здесь магия, за ранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем примере `AnimalService` вообще никак не задействован. Строка `Animal animal = applicationContext.getBean(Animal.class)` пытается получить из контекста бин класса `Animal`, а там таких два. Исправьте на

```
Animal animal = applicationContext.getBean("kitty", Animal.class)
```

или на

```
AnimalService animalService = applicationContext.getBean(AnimalService.class)
```

Comment: А почему если добавить аннотацию @Primary все начинает работать?

Comment: Эта аннотация помечает бин как первичный. В случае неопределённости контекст будет отдавать именно его.

Answer (score 3):

Вы создали класс сервис AnimalService и указали в нём  @Qualifier, но этот сервис вы нигде не используете, а сразу в Main вызываете Animal.

Попробуйте в Main получать bean AnimalService, а затем из него получать нужный Animal путём вызова метода  getAnimal()

Comment: Да я так тоже так делал, но интересует почему же при добавлении аннотации @Primary все работает?

Comment: @Primary указывает какой бин брать по умолчанию, если вы не указали это через параметр в getBean или не указали через Qualifier

Comment: например тут есть пример и описание с Primary http://eusenko.blogspot.com/2015/05/spring-primary.html